# Add select box to html using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select

Select box shows empty. Where is error in my code?

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" /></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#2').click(function() {
        $("#element").append(
        "                    <select name='select'>",
        "                            <option>Kč</option>",
        "                            <option>Euro</option>",
        "                   </select>"
        );
    });
});
</script>

<select>
    <option id="1">1</option>
    <option id="2">2</option>
</select>

<div id="element"></div>
```

Comment: Using numbers as ID's isn't advisable..

Answer (score 2):

When you select an option in a select box .click() is not available.

What you need for that is .change().

http://jsfiddle.net/uEMvr/

**HTML**

```
<select id="selectList">
    <option id="1">1</option>
    <option id="2">2</option>
</select>

<div id="element"></div>
```

**JS**

```
$('#selectList').change(function(){ 
    if($(this).val() == "2"){
        $("#element").append(
            "<select name='select'>" +
            "<option>Kč</option>" +
            "<option>Euro</option>" +
            "</select>"
        );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but try something that:

```
  $('#id2').click(function() {
      $("#element").append(
      "<select name='select'>" +
          "<option>Kč</option>" + 
          "<option>Euro</option>"+
        "</select>");
  });
```

In your code you append to element something that:

```
<select></select>
<option>Kč</option>
<option>Euro</option>
```

**Also like @Zenith mention you can't use `ID` which starts from numbers!!**
So change id's to for example `id1` and `id2`;

Comment: ok, thank you and how add element using click on button in this code? <button id="add">ADD Element</button>

Comment: add this element using select box and click on button "add"

Comment: Code is perfekt and works, but I can not add button, who add elements instead of select box, but select remains.

Comment: Someting: <select id="selectList">
    <option id="1">1</option>
    <option id="2">2</option>
</select>}
<button id="add">ADD</button>
<div id="element"></div>

JS
$('#add').click(function(){ 
$('#selectList').change(function(){ 
    if($(this).val() == "2"){
        $("#element").append(
            "<select name='select'>" +
            "<option>Kč</option>" +
            "<option>Euro</option>" +
            "</select>"
        );
    }
});});

Comment: So upvote if I help or write your own answer and accept it if noone of us help you.